# Special $k$-algebra is finitely generated

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebras

Let $B$ be a $k$-algebra such that there exist finitely many elements $b_1,\dots,b_n \in B$ satisfying:

- $(b_1,\dots,b_n) = B$ (equivalently, there are elements $c_1,\dots,c_n \in B$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i c_i = 1$)
- The localization $B_{b_i}$ at $b_i$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra for all $b_i$'s.

Show that $B$ is finitely generated.

I am tempted to take the $b_i$'s and $c_i$'s as generators, but I am not really sure about what the finitely generated localizations tell me... any hints?

Comment: You also want to take denominators.

Comment: What do you mean by $(b_1, \dots, b_n) = B$? That $B$ is finitely generated as a ring and thus you want to show that $B$ is finitely generated over $k$? as algebra?

Comment: @RadekSuchánek I'd suppose this means that $(b_i)$ generate $B$ as a submodule (as an ideal), but not necessarily as an algebra.

Comment: @lisyarus Exactly

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff Which denominators? $\frac{1}{b_i}$ is not in $B$, in general

Comment: Heh, I meant numerators. My bad. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $B_i$ for the localization of $B$ at $b_i$. That $B_i$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra means there are $a_{1,i},\ldots,a_{n_i,i}$ in $B$ such that for each $b\in B$, we can find $N>0$ such that $b_i^N b$ is a polynomial in the $a_{1,i},\ldots,a_{n_i,i}$. Now pick $b\in B$, and note that taking $N$ very large we can take $N$ that works for each $i$, so that $b_i^Nb$ is a polynomial in $a_{i,1},\cdots,a_{i,n_i}$. Now since the $b_i$ generate $1$, taking a large power shows that the $b_i^N$ do too. This means you can write
$$b = 1\cdot b = \sum c_i b_i^N b $$

a polynomial in all the $a_{i,j}$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I am still missing a detail, though: why do the $b_i^N$ generate $1$?

Comment: Maybe I've got it: since there is no maximal ideal that contains all the $b_i$, there is also no maximal ideal that contains all the $b_i^N$ (because, being prime, it would contain all the $b_i$), so the ideal generated by all the $b_i^N$ is again $(1)$.

Comment: @57Jimmy Yes, that's perfect.

Comment: @57Jimmy Observe I haven't specified what the $k$-algebra generators are, however, be sure to pin them down. ;)

Comment: I think one should take all the $a_{ij}, b_i$ and $c_i$, right?